# How to pass data using javascript in libgdx html5 app?

Tags: javascript, libgdx

I just created a server for my libgdx html5 app and I want to be able to use some js files to pass data to the libgdx html project.

Does anyone know if it is possible and any good tutorials on it? Anyone know how it can be done? Any advice will be appreciated.